# How to use ANTLR3 lexer only, without parser?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, lexer, parser-generator

I need to use lexer only in ANTLR3, i don't need parser. How can i do it ? I use the following code (in main.c), which i found somehwere in the internet.

```
    #include <CLexer.h>
#include <CParser.h>

int ANTLR3_CDECL

main    (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pANTLR3_UINT8               fileName;
    pANTLR3_INPUT_STREAM        inputStream;
    pCLexer                     cLexer;
    pANTLR3_COMMON_TOKEN_STREAM tokenStream;
    pCParser                    cParser;

    // Имя входного файла по умолчанию - "input", но
    // его можно задать аргументом программы
    //
    if (argc < 2 || argv[1] == NULL)
    {
        fileName = (pANTLR3_UINT8) "./input";
    }
    else
    {
        fileName = (pANTLR3_UINT8) argv[1];
    }

    // Открываем входной поток, связанный с этим файлом
    //
    inputStream = antlr3AsciiFileStreamNew(fileName);
    if ( inputStream == NULL)
    {
        // Аварийный выход (файл не открывается)
        //
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s\n", (char *) fileName);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Создаём лексер, связанный с открытым потоком
    //
    cLexer = CLexerNew(inputStream);
    if ( cLexer == NULL )
    {
        // Аварийный выход (закончилась память, лол)
        //
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create the lexer due to malloc() failure1\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Получаем поток токенов из входных данных
    //
    tokenStream = antlr3CommonTokenStreamSourceNew(ANTLR3_SIZE_HINT, 
                                                   TOKENSOURCE(cLexer));
    if (tokenStream == NULL)
    {
        // Аварийный выход (закончилась память)
        //
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory trying to allocate token stream\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Создаём парсер, связанный с потоком токенов
    //
    cParser = CParserNew(tokenStream);
    if (cParser == NULL)
    {
        // Аварийный выход (закончилась память, хотя, мне кажется,
        // что здесь более вероятны другие причины ошибки)
        //
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory trying to allocate parser\n");
        exit(ANTLR3_ERR_NOMEM);
    }

    // Не знаю
    //
    cParser->translation_unit(cParser);

    // Уничтожаем созданные "объекты" в том порядке, в котором их создавали
    //
    cParser ->free(cParser);
    cParser = NULL;
    tokenStream ->free(tokenStream);
    tokenStream = NULL;
    cLexer ->free (cLexer);
    cLexer = NULL;
    inputStream ->close (inputStream);
    inputStream = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

But looks like it uses parser too, because i'm getting tons of parsing errors in console, when i try to use it.

Comment: When you get `cLexer` from `cLexer = CLexerNew(inputStream);`, what you want is there in it. I don't know what else you would like to know.

Comment: OP here. I have the grammar file (lightly edited by me), here is it http://rghost.ru/40968674

Comment: All of i need is getting token list in output console

Answer (score 1):

Use getTokens() on the tokenStream 'object' to get an ANTLR vector of the tokens. Then print the contents of the vector.

```
//This runs fillBuffer() which is the function that runs the lexer to completion
pANTLR3_VECTOR tList = tokenStream->getTokens(tokenStream);

pANTLR3_COMMON_TOKEN token = tList->get(tList,0);
```